# Sortable.js is not working: List items are not draggable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, rubaxa-sortable

I have tried a very simple example with Sortable.js: Two lists: One is currently empty, and will store item copies from the other list (which is static).

I tried defining pull and put values for each list, defining the same group name, but it does not work. In fact the static elements from the filled list are not draggable at all.

I have written the [example at JSbin](http://jsbin.com/likaci/3/edit?html,js,output). Since I am new to JS, I accept all kind of constructive comments.

BTW: any way of drawing the bootstrap list borders even when empty?

Comment: your jsbin is not working for me

Comment: @Gokhan Well, that's weird! I tried opening with incognito mode and the link worked. How should I share the link then?

Comment: Which Sortables plugin are you using? You have `long_list_element` being passed, where is it defined?

Comment: @anpsmn Sorry about that, a typo when changing names to create the JSBin example. Each list is created with the whatever_list_element var created just the line above. I'm using https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the jsbin and did the following corrections

- Replaced the sortable.js with

  ```
   <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sortable/latest/Sortable.min.js"></s‌​cript>
  ```
- You were accessing the ids with `_` (instances_list, main_list) whereas the ids were having an `-`
- For the appending to work I had to add one item by default to `instances-list` than keeping it empty

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fedafiyopi/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: So the problem was a bad version of Sortable.js? (apaprt from the _ to - typo, of course). ANyway, isn't it possible to achieve this having the instances-list empty? It seems achievable at the Sortable.js examples webpage

Comment: Can you give me the link for the example page?

Comment: Btw, it is INCREDIBLY discourteous to spam another persons GitHub pages with requests what with the limited network usage in place. Your script should be included like so: <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sortable/latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>